# When does pthread_timedjoin_np() return EBUSY?

Tags: c, error-handling, pthreads, error-code, pthread-join

I am trying to handle all the possible return values of `pthread_timedjoin_np()`, but I did not quite understand, when does it return `EBUSY`?

If the thread returns within the given time `pthread_timedjoin_np()` always returns zero, while if time has passed I get `ETIMEDOUT`. What do I have to do to trigger `EBUSY`?

Comment: https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/b92a49359f33a461db080a33940d73f47c756126/nptl/pthread_timedjoin.c -> https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/b92a49359f33a461db080a33940d73f47c756126/nptl/pthread_join_common.c I don't see it, so never?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I did not quite understand, when does it return EBUSY?

Never.

The man page that you are reading is for both `pthread_tryjoin_np` and `pthread_timedjoin_np`. `pthread_tryjoin_np` will return with `EBUSY` when "thread had not yet terminated at the time of the call".

> These functions can fail with the same errors as pthread_join(3).
> **pthread_tryjoin_np() can in addition fail with the** following    error:
>
> EBUSY  thread had not yet terminated at the time of the call.

> **pthread_timedjoin_np() can in addition fail with the following
> errors:**
>
> EINVAL abstime value is invalid (tv_sec is less than 0 or tv_nsec
> is greater than 1e9).
>
> ETIMEDOUT
> The call timed out before thread terminated.

Comment: Oh I see it now. My bad. The documentation is really confusing!